# Gridview null reference exception c#

Tags: c#, gridview

I am adding data in gridview on button click event through following code:

```
            int row = 0;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
            dataGridView1["Description",row].Value = name;
            dataGridView1["Quantity", row].Value = qty.Text;
            dataGridView1["Price", row].Value = p;
            dataGridView1["Discountcell", row].Value = "0000";
            dataGridView1["amt", row].Value = tot;
```

its working perfectly fine.
now i want when I enter discount in[image: gridview], discount should minus from total amount. for this I have following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int n = item.Index;
               dataGridView1["amt", n].Value = tot - float.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            }
```

Here it gives me following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Sales System1.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

without this subtracting code data is added in gridview. but when I put this code it gives above error. What I need to do?

Comment: What is `tot`?? is it define somewhere?

Comment: tot is amount which I am getting from multiplying price to quantity

Comment: Do a null check on the cell value or use TryParse.

Comment: Can you check what element is null at where this exception is thrown

Comment: @ReadyFreddy how can I check tell me?

Comment: @Sami where I null check or try parse?

Comment: Does "dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value" has value or it is Null? Try Float.TryParse instead of Float.Parse. You can go for Quick Watch at this statement.

Comment: @Abhijit_Srikumar no overload method for tryparse. It give above syntax error when I tryParse

Comment: @Abhijit_Srikumar yes it has value **0000**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the `AllowUserToAddRows` setted to `true`, the `dataGridView1.Rows` includes the editor row in the list of rows.

Infact, the last value assigned to the `item` variable in the `foreach` cycle is exactly that row (editor row). If you don't want to set the `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false` you can skip processing that row using the `IsNewRow` property of the row itself.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (item.IsNewRow) break;
    dataGridView1["amt", item.Index].Value = tot - float.Parse(item.Cells["Discountcell"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    float f;
    int n = item.Index;
    if (float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out f))
    {
         dataGridView1["amt", n].Value = tot - f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir error is because it go on next row also which is not yet added, because editing is enabled. now please tell me which I do to no have this error